# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: macos, memcached, osx-lion, libevent

I've checked a number of similar questions on stackoverflow but haven't found an answer yet.

I'm trying to install memcached on Lion OSX as [shown here](http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2009/08/30/install-memcached-php-extension-on-os-x-snow-leopard/).

Here's what I'm getting:

```
j-court-demones-macbook-pro:libevent-1.4.12-stable jcourtdemone$ ./configure; make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've reinstalled Xcode as was recommended in a couple places, but no dice.

Here's my config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.63.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = j-court-demones-macbook-pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 11.3.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 109 tasks, 599 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 0.98, Mach factor: 7.01
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/X11/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2077: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2145: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2156: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2199: result: yes
configure:2224: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2263: result: ./install-sh -c -d
configure:2276: checking for gawk
configure:2306: result: no
configure:2276: checking for mawk
configure:2306: result: no
configure:2276: checking for nawk
configure:2306: result: no
configure:2276: checking for awk
configure:2292: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2303: result: awk
configure:2314: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2336: result: yes
configure:2575: checking for gcc
configure:2591: found /Developer/usr/bin/gcc
configure:2602: result: gcc
configure:2834: checking for C compiler version
configure:2842: gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5484)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2846: $? = 0
configure:2853: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin9
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5484~1/src/configure --disable-checking -enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.0/ --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.0.0 --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin9 --with-arch=apple --with-tune=generic --host=i686-apple-darwin9 --target=i686-apple-darwin9
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5484)
configure:2857: $? = 0
configure:2864: gcc -V >&5
gcc-4.0: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2868: $? = 1
configure:2891: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2913: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.5.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2917: $? = 1
configure:2955: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE "libevent"
| #define VERSION "1.4.12-stable"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2961: error: in `/tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable':
configure:2964: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/missing --run aclocal-1.10'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/missing --run tar'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/missing --run automake-1.10'
AWK='awk'
BUILD_WIN32_FALSE=''
BUILD_WIN32_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DSYMUTIL=''
ECHO='/bin/echo'
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77=''
FFLAGS=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOL_DEPS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='./install-sh -c -d'
NMEDIT=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='libevent'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION='1.4.12-stable'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_F77=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='$(SHELL) /tmp/libevent-1.4.12-stable/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(top_builddir)/./install-sh -c -d'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE "libevent"
#define VERSION "1.4.12-stable"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: To save people hunting through your log, the real error is: `ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.5.o`

Comment: The question is, have you ever compiled anything else on this machine before, or is this the first time?

Comment: I feel like I have, but it's a newer computer, so I might be thinking of my last one.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with trying to compile a simple "hello world" program first, just to see whether you've got everything installed properly.

Comment: What type of Hello World program would I be looking for? I gave a quick search and found a lot of stuff for C++ and Java, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm really dealing with here... This really isn't my strongest area.

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't really *programming* related, but more about *installation of software*. If you don't know anything about programming, then there are better places to find the kind of help you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the "not programming related" judgement. The issue her seem to be one of have the developer tools installed and configured ('course, I thought they were installed by default on Lion). If that is the case this would be "tools unique to the programming profession" or what ever it is that the FAQ says.

Comment: I found this item because I'm experiencing a very similar problem trying to build an iOS library on a machine on which I've been definitely programming for some time. Seems very valid to me!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23508250/1999993) solved it for me - it was a licence thing.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You have an old set of developer tools. gcc is reporting its version as 4.0.1. This may be left over from migrating from an older version of the OS. If you've installed Xcode 4.3.x, you need to launch it, go into its preferences, select the Locations tab, and click "Install" next to the Command Line Tools package.

Comment: If you are reading this answer, this is definitely something you should do, but be aware that it will not solve your problem with other packages you are trying to build. So first install the command line tools then see the answer below by @sterescott and that should take care of your problems. Some packages like mod_jk use `/usr/sbin/apxs -q CC` in configure to ask for the C compiler. APXS spits it out, but it has the wrong path so that's why you keep getting errors.

Comment: This helped, but the final fix came from here: http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2011/08/29/install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: Command line Tools packages ars now available at: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: In Xcode 7 the Command Line Tools is located at the Locations tab. In my case I fixed the problem installing python by selecting Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: If someone is reading this in 2017 or later, you should set the system date back to feb 2013 or there will be an error claiming the Bluetooth pkg is untrusted. Some problem with an expired certificate.

Answer (score 143):

I have 10.8 installed and Xcode 4.4 with Command Line tools, and yet I was still getting this error. Rather than reinstall Xcode, I noticed there were two relevant lines in my config.log:

```
configure:5130: checking for C compiler version
configure:5139: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc --version >&5
```

That path did not exist for me. Instead I had:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
```

The C compiler ("cc") is located inside of that xctoolchain directory. I created a symlink for OSX10.8.xctoolchain to point to XcodeDefault.xctoolchain and that fixed it. Now the memcached installation script can find the compiler version and continue on its way.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains
sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.8.xctoolchain
```

As suggested in the comments, if you are having this problem on Yosemite (10.10) or Mavericks (10.9), you can update the symlink command above to point to that specific version (`OSX10.9.xctoolchain` or `OSX10.10.xctoolchain`).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!  I have a fresh installation of OSX 10.8 and the latest Xcode + Command Line Tools, so this doesn't seem to have been a problem related to upgrading OSX.

Comment: @James Great point. I too had a fresh installation of OSX 10.8.

Comment: cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains;sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.8.xctoolchain

Comment: This did not work for me. What worked for me was upgrading my command line tools (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19993810/130664).

Comment: Same thing on on Mavericks: sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.9.xctoolchain

Comment: +1 I was trying to build Tcl. There was already a `gcc` executable but Tcl was looking for `gcc-4.0`, so I just did: `ln -s gcc gcc-4.0`

Comment: This worked for me on Yosemite as well: `sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.10.xctoolchain`

Comment: The same with OS X 10.9
  sudo ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.9.xctoolchain

Comment: Or we can directly use this command its working for me 
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: What if we did not installed `Xcode.app`?

Answer (score 78):

When you see this error message, you might not have accepted the *Xcode license agreement* yet after an upgrade.

First of all, make sure you have upgraded your commandline tools:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Now Apple wants you to agree to their license before you can use these tools:

```
$ gcc
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

$ sudo gcc
You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.
[...]
```

After you have accepted it, the commandline tools will work as expected.

Comment: This worked for me; Xcode was install (clean Mavericks installation) but the command-line tools weren't automatically installed.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. I was installing iperf3 and I kept getting the error: "c compiler cannot install executables". I used "xcode-select --install" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This seems to fix the issue on Yosemite; even though XCode 6 now comes with the command tools pre-installed, and I could run clang from the command line, ./configure failed until I ran xcode-select

Comment: Some system/security updates seem to disable the license agreement and you have to go through this step again.

Comment: Happened after an El Capitan beta install.

Comment: This worked for me in MacOS Sierra (beta 2) using Xcode 8.0b

Answer (score 13):

I had already installed the command line tools in xcode but I mine still errored out on:

```
line 3619: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
```

When I entered `which gcc` it returned

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

When I entered `gcc -v` I got a bunch of stuff then

```
..  
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

So I created a symlink:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.2
```

And it worked!

(the config.log file is located in the directory that make is trying to build something in)

Comment: In the config.log I saw that CC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' but I did an ls of the directory and there was nothing. So it was pretty clear this way the issue. I created the symlink and BAM! All good.

Comment: After much searching this is exactly the trick I needed! Thanks-

Comment: ln: gcc-4.2.1: Operation not permitted.
I am getting this error when trying these steps.

Answer (score 12):

I just had this issue building apache.  The solution I used was the same as Mostafa, I had to export 2 variables:

```
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
CPP='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E'
```

This was one Mac OSX Mavericks

Comment: Thanks, this worked on OS X for running `./configure` in for Apache

Answer (score 7):

Setting 'clang' as the compiler configure should use worked for me:

```
export CC=clang
pip install --no-clean pycrypto
```

Comment: `export CC=clang` solved for me. In my case I was getting this error when trying to install xdebug with `pecl install xdebug`.

Answer (score 6):

First get the gcc path using

> Command: **which gcc**
>
> Output: /usr/bin/gcc

I had the same issue, Please set the gcc path in below command and install

> **CC=/usr/bin/gcc rvm install 1.9.3**

Later if you get "*Ruby was built without documentation*" run below command

> **rvm docs generate-ri**

Comment: Works on High Sierra too

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a problem with gcc, highlighted by `gcc -v`. It was down to upgrading Xcode recently [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11975148/1050862) said to do `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I furiously read all of this page, hoping to find a solution for:

```
"configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables"
```

In the end nothing worked, because my problem was a "typing" one, and was related to CFLAGS.
In my .bash_profile file I had:

```
export ARM_ARCH="arm64”
export CFLAGS="-arch ${ARM_ARCH}"
```

As you can observe --- export ARM_ARCH=**"arm64”** --- the last quote sign is not the same with the first quote sign. The first one ( " ) is legal while the second one ( ” ) is not.
This happended because I made the mistake to use TextEdit (I'm working under MacOS), and this is apparently a feature called SmartQuotes: the quote sign CHANGES BY ITSELF TO THE ILLEGAL STYLE whenever you edit something just next to it.
Lesson learned: use a proper text editor...

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is coming here because RVM / Ruby is creating issues (Middleman/Grunt) I've solved my issue.

PS. The answer by steroscott fixed my issue a while back...this time around not the case.

In my case rvm is trying to use a downloaded gcc via homebrew. I ran a brew uninstall of gcc (gcc46 for me) and reran the code for the ruby installation (old project old ruby v)

```
$ brew uninstall gcc46

$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

during that process of checking for requirements it automatically fetched a newer gcc for me and boom, all is working now. Oh a big note, the gcc install from the rvm command can take around 10-15 minutes without throwing out any text, it's not frozen :) Good luck

Comment: The important message from *rbenv* was for me:

For most programs the `llvm-gcc` compiler works fine. However,
versions of Ruby older than 1.9.3-p125 are incompatible with
`llvm-gcc`. To build older versions of Ruby you must have the official
GCC compiler installed on your system.

TO FIX THE PROBLEM: Install Homebrew's apple-gcc42 package with this
command: brew tap homebrew/dupes ; brew install apple-gcc42

Comment: `Error: No available formula with the name "gcc46". Did you mean gcc@6, gcc, gcc@4.9, gcc@9, gcc@8, gcc@7 or gcc@5?
`

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue building react-native app when I try to install Pod. I had to export 2 variables:

```
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
CPP='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried  `xcode-select --install` but it says that it's not available from the store. Then, inspired by Rimian, I checked my gcc : `gcc -v` and then I got a message saying I did not aggreed.

From that point I just followed the agreement process from `gcc -v`, after I agreed it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces in your Xcode application name (can happen if you keep older versions around - for example renaming it 'Xcode 4.app'); build tools will be referenced within the Xcode bundle paths, and many scripts can't handle references with spaces properly.

Answer (score 0):

About clang iOS cross-compiler

I've found that the problem was at `miphoneos-version-min=5.0` . I've changed into `miphoneos-version-min=8.0` . Now it works.

I just want suggest to use create a simple test.c file and compile it by the command write in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Ensures the path to Xcode.app bundle is without space or strange characters. I have Xcode installed in ~/Downloads/Last Dev Tools/ folder, so with spaces and renaming the folder to LastDevTools fixed this (after resetting xcode-select -p though)

Answer (score 0):

Check where your `clang` is located:

```
which clang
```

It should be somewhere under `/usr/bin/clang`.
In my case from old times it was coming from Miniconda that was put artificially on the command line PATH. Fix that so that clang comes from Xcode and that should bring you forward.

Answer (score 0):

After having struggled with this for a long while, I finally got it to work. I just ran the command with sudo.

```
sudo ./configure
```