# Error: GCC 4.8.1 cannot create executables

Tags: curl, configure, gcc4.8

Before this gets flagged as a duplicate, I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357804/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables#10358412) question, and tried the symlink method suggested there. It did not work.

I'm on a system running OS X 10.8.5, with Xcode 5.0 and GCC 4.8.1, installed independently of Command Line Tools/Developer Tools. When trying to install `cURL`, I get this error upon running `./configure`:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/me/Downloads/curl-7.32.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Upon checking the `config.log`, I found this:

```
configure:4126: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

As well as this:

```
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "curl"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "curl"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "-"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "curl -"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "a suitable curl mailing list: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int main (void)
| {
| 
|  ;
|  return 0;
| }
```

I'm not sure whether that first part played a role in the `./configure` failure, and I'm entirely unsure what to make of the latter part.

How can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `configure` was unable to find your specified C compiler.  Check that at least one of the following is true:

1. Your compiler is located in a directory in your `$PATH` environment variable.
2. The `CC=` argument to your invocation of `configure` is a valid path to the compiler.