# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables with Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I've checked stackoverflow but haven't found an answer yet.

I'm trying to install wget on Mavericks as shown here.

Here's what I'm getting:

```
bolo:wget-1.14 Michelin$ subl config.log 
bolo:wget-1.14 Michelin$ ./configure --with-ssl=openssl
configure: configuring for GNU Wget 1.14
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Michelin/Downloads/wget-1.14':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

My config.log:

https://gist.github.com/bolom/7552389

Other thing I have installed Command Line tools BUT I don't the assembler :(

B.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Mavericks, but from you config.log it looks like configure can't find *as*, the assembler.  It's usually in /usr/bin.  Make sure it's there.  If it's not, try to find it (someone with a Mavericks installation may have more information)

Comment: you're rigth, i don't have it

Comment: However the command line tool is here http://cl.ly/image/3m2U1N0q1B2l

Answer (score 4):

Below solved this for me in Mavericks. I had to use sudo for this to work.

From https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist

Xcode License Agreement

When attempting to build a port which compiles an OS X app (e.g., gimp-app), the compilation may fail with an xcodebuild error. One of the possible causes of this is that an initial run of xcodebuild from the terminal may be needed to accept the EULA before any compilation can proceed. Run:

xcodebuild -license

from a terminal window and follow the prompts. After accepting the EULA, rebuild the port again.

With some ports and some versions of Xcode (e.g. libunwind-headers with Xcode 4.4+) you may need to accept the license as root, i.e.:

sudo xcodebuild -license

This will need to be repeated after any Xcode upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

i'd suggest using homebrew (http://brew.sh/) to install wget:

```
brew install wget
```

an additional note for others out there: upgrading your command line tools for Mavericks is easy like this: http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue when working with Mac Ports for the first time.

When you newly install Xcode and command line tools, there's a license agreement you have to agree to first before the tools (and indeed Xcode) actually work.

Bring up a terminal session and type "ac" (no quotes)

You will be prompted to accept the license agreement.  Page down and enter 'agree' at the end.

You should then be good too go!

Compiles worked for me from that point on.

Cheers