# Compiling Python 2.7.5 issues

Tags: python, macos, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile Python 2.7.5 into a static library without its parser. When I run

```
./configure --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc" CPPFLAGS="-static" CC=gcc
```

or

```
./configure --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc" CPPFLAGS="-static"
```

I get this response every time.

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... darwin
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... $(PLATMACDIRS)
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Anthony/Desktop/Projects/Python-2.7.5':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I see what the error's are, but I don't know how to fix them. I have installed gcc via home-brew and followed along here: https://coderwall.com/p/lqpp8w to get it setup for 10.9, but it seems to fail.

Is there a way to compile it via CLANG/LLVM into a static library?

Any ideas? Thanks

**Update:** I forgot to post the config.log. http://cl.ly/TA4b:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 2.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-shared LDFLAGS=-static -static-libgcc CPPFLAGS=-static

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Anthonys-VM.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.0.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for a single processor only.
1 processor is physically available.
1 processor is logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processor active: 0
Primary memory available: 2.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 145 tasks, 502 threads, 1 processors
Load average: 1.00, Mach factor: 0.00
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /Developer/Tools/Panda3D


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2782: checking build system type
configure:2796: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:2816: checking host system type
configure:2829: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:2937: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:2978: result: no
configure:2987: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:3004: result: 32-bit
configure:3161: checking MACHDEP
configure:3353: result: darwin
configure:3359: checking EXTRAPLATDIR
configure:3374: result: $(PLATMACDIRS)
configure:3395: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3439: result: no
configure:3533: checking for gcc
configure:3549: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3560: result: gcc
configure:3789: checking for C compiler version
configure:3798: gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3809: $? = 0
configure:3798: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /Volumes/Media/Builds/gcc-5666.3/build/obj/src/configure --disable-checking --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++,fortran --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
configure:3809: $? = 0
configure:3798: gcc -V >&5
gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:3809: $? = 1
configure:3798: gcc -qversion >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
configure:3809: $? = 1
configure:3829: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3851: gcc  -static -static -static-libgcc conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3855: $? = 1
configure:3893: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3898: error: in `/Users/Anthony/Desktop/Projects/Python-2.7.5':
configure:3900: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-static
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-static -static-libgcc'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BASECPPFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=' '\''--disable-shared'\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-static -static-libgcc'\'' '\''CPPFLAGS=-static'\'''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-static'
CXX=''
DEFS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXTRAMACHDEPPATH='$(PLATMACPATH)'
EXTRAPLATDIR='$(PLATMACDIRS)'
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/usr/local'
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_HG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
HGBRANCH=''
HGTAG=''
HGVERSION=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS='-static -static-libgcc'
LDLAST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MACHDEP='darwin'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
MKDIR_P=''
MULTIARCH=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 2.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
PYTHON_FOR_BUILD='./$(BUILDPYTHON) -E'
RANLIB=''
RUNSHARED=''
SGI_ABI=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIBS=''
SIGNAL_OBJS=''
SO=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
SVNVERSION=''
THREADHEADERS=''
THREADOBJ=''
TRUE=''
UNICODE_OBJS=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
USE_SIGNAL_MODULE=''
USE_THREAD_MODULE=''
VERSION='2.7'
_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin13.0.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin13.0.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _BSD_TYPES 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: `checking whether the C compiler works... no` - do you have xcode command line tools installed?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I forgot to attach that. Added it now.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have them installed.

Comment: Do you have _just_ the command line tools or all of xcode installed as well? What do you get when you do `ls -l /usr/lib/crt*`?

Comment: Xcode 5.0.2 is also installed. I've also reinstalled the command-line tools just for the heck of it.

Comment: Your problem is that the linker cannot find a library (`ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`); generally its located in `/usr/lib/`, and this path should be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Sometimes the actual library is versioned, and you need to create a symlink so that the linker will work.

Comment: You could probably start out with "export CC=clang".  You appear to be using gcc right now.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How would I fix the missing library? —– Here is the output for the command you gave me:

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   9168 Jan  1 22:24 /usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   8900 Jan  1 22:24 /usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  10268 Jan  1 22:24 /usr/lib/crt1.o

Comment: @dstromberg Right, I am trying to use GCC as its the best way to build python into a static library.

Comment: Related if not duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357804/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I have installed the Xcode Command line tools. I am on 10.9 so I can't install the Xcode 4 tools. As for sum-linking the toolchain, I have done all of that and still receive the same error. Should it maybe added to my $PATH?

Comment: A rather basic suggestion. Can you start gcc manually? Just the command? It should print something about missing a source file, but it should start. Or try  gcc --version  (I don't know if you system has it, but 'which gcc' should tell you where the executable is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but it turns out, all I needed to do was run ./configure as it compiles statically by default.