# Geo libaries (i.e .a files ) are Missing in ShapeKit project for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, maps, mkmapview, gis

I downloaded shapekit for GeoWKB/WKT format to show in MapView for iOS from github, but .a files are missing in it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Read through the [Github page](https://github.com/mweisman/ShapeKit) there are instructions to build Shapekit. Please follow them.

> ShapeKit depends on GEOS and PROJ. There is a build script in lib_src which will automate downloading and building universal libraries for both ARMv7 and x86 (simulator) and will copy the libraries and headers to the ShapeKit library directory. To use it, simply run the build_libs.sh script in the lib_src directory to install the libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and tried, but i got error when exec this command "sh build_ios -p $PWD/device_build device"                    checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/Users/admin/geos-3.2.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Comment: @Sudheshna_suri Maybe you need to update your command line tools for Xcode. Take a look at this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357804/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables

Comment: I run app finally, it workes.... but i want to  only load WKB geomentry in mapView. when i try it getting crash

Comment: @Sudheshna_suri You can ask new question along with crash report, relevant code and any other details.