# unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++' gcc (Homebrew gcc 5.3.0) 5.3.0

Tags: c++, gcc, homebrew, std, osx-elcapitan

I run Mac OSX El Capitan, I have installed via Homebrew gcc version 5.3.0.

I want to install pyopencl (but as I understand it doesn't matter) and when running the following command:

> gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pyopencl -DPYGPU_PYOPENCL=1 -Isrc/c_wrapper/ -I/Users/earendilllock/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/pyopencl._cffi.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/pyopencl._cffi.o -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk

I have  obtained the following error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I could not find the solution for resolving that problem via Google, but I hope it exists.

Answer (score 16):

As the error message says, the gcc compiler has no such commandline option as `-stdlib`. The LLVM clang compiler does. 
That is because clang offers you the choice of linking the LLVM standard C++ library (`libc++`) or the
GNU standard C++ library (`libstdc++`), whereas gcc supports only `libstdc++`.

Delete the option `-stdlib=libc++`. You might as well also replace `-std=c++0x` with `-std=c++11`,
since the former denotes experimental support for the 2011 C++11 standard, applicable for gcc versions
4.3 through 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be useful to install the clang/clang++ compiler and use this when it comes to the build step (because you are likely to run into gcc issues with other Python packages):

```
python configure.py
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
python setup.py build
make -j 4
python setup.py install
cd ../
python -c "import pyopencl"
```