# pip3 fails to install imread - 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, pip, imread

when I do pip3 install imread I get the following error:

```
Collecting imread
  Using cached imread-0.7.4.tar.gz (151 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from imread) (1.17.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: imread
  Building wheel for imread (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-wheel-th30_vsf
       cwd: /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/
  Complete output (125 lines):
  sh: pkg-config: command not found
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/imread_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/ijrois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/special.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_tiff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_rois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_webp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_jpeg.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_imread_from_blob.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_xcf.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_formats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_imsave.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_bad.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_bmp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/good.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/bit1.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/1_webp_a.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/rois.zip -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/rgba.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/ghsystem_flame.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/star1.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/stack.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/T -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/0186-0099.roi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.unknown -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/good -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/arange512_16bit.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/diag.xcf -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/palette_zero.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/py-installer-indexed.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/mono.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF/00r00.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r05.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r04.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r06.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r03.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r02.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r00.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r01.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  running build_ext
  building 'imread._imread' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/_imread.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/_imread.o -stdlib=libc++
  In file included from imread/_imread.cpp:20:
  imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
          void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                               ^
  1 warning generated.
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/lib/formats.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib/formats.o -stdlib=libc++
  In file included from imread/lib/formats.cpp:4:
  In file included from imread/lib/formats.h:6:
  imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
          void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                               ^
  In file included from imread/lib/formats.cpp:9:
  imread/lib/_tiff.h:41:37: warning: 'STKFormat::read_multi' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
          std::unique_ptr<image_list> read_multi(byte_source* s, ImageFactory* f);
                                      ^
  imread/lib/base.h:239:45: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'ImageFormat::read_multi' declared here: different number of parameters (3 vs 2)
          virtual std::unique_ptr<image_list> read_multi(byte_source* src, ImageFactory* factory, const options_map&) {
                                              ^
  2 warnings generated.
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/lib/numpy.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib/numpy.o -stdlib=libc++
  In file included from imread/lib/numpy.cpp:4:
  In file included from imread/lib/numpy.h:8:
  imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
          void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                               ^
  1 warning generated.
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/lib/_bmp.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib/_bmp.o -stdlib=libc++
  In file included from imread/lib/_bmp.cpp:5:
  imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
          void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                               ^
  imread/lib/_bmp.cpp:108:12: error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Image, std::__1::default_delete<Image> >'
      return output;
             ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2535:3: note: declared private here
    unique_ptr(unique_ptr&);
    ^
  1 warning and 1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imread
  Running setup.py clean for imread
Failed to build imread
Installing collected packages: imread
    Running setup.py install for imread ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-record-7oz3j6hu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/imread
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/
    Complete output (125 lines):
    sh: pkg-config: command not found
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/imread_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/ijrois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/special.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_tiff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_rois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_webp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_jpeg.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_imread_from_blob.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_xcf.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_formats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_imsave.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_bad.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_bmp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/good.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/bit1.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/1_webp_a.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/rois.zip -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/rgba.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/ghsystem_flame.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/star1.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/stack.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/T -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/0186-0099.roi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.unknown -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/good -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/arange512_16bit.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/diag.xcf -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/palette_zero.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/py-installer-indexed.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/mono.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF/00r00.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r05.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r04.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r06.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r03.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r02.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r00.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r01.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    running build_ext
    building 'imread._imread' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/_imread.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/_imread.o -stdlib=libc++
    In file included from imread/_imread.cpp:20:
    imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/lib/formats.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib/formats.o -stdlib=libc++
    In file included from imread/lib/formats.cpp:4:
    In file included from imread/lib/formats.h:6:
    imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                                 ^
    In file included from imread/lib/formats.cpp:9:
    imread/lib/_tiff.h:41:37: warning: 'STKFormat::read_multi' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
            std::unique_ptr<image_list> read_multi(byte_source* s, ImageFactory* f);
                                        ^
    imread/lib/base.h:239:45: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'ImageFormat::read_multi' declared here: different number of parameters (3 vs 2)
            virtual std::unique_ptr<image_list> read_multi(byte_source* src, ImageFactory* factory, const options_map&) {
                                                ^
    2 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/lib/numpy.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib/numpy.o -stdlib=libc++
    In file included from imread/lib/numpy.cpp:4:
    In file included from imread/lib/numpy.h:8:
    imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/lib/_bmp.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib/_bmp.o -stdlib=libc++
    In file included from imread/lib/_bmp.cpp:5:
    imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
                                                 ^
    imread/lib/_bmp.cpp:108:12: error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Image, std::__1::default_delete<Image> >'
        return output;
               ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2535:3: note: declared private here
      unique_ptr(unique_ptr&);
      ^
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-yzh0j2tc/imread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-record-7oz3j6hu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/imread Check the logs for full command output.
```

I already tried with `pip3 install imread --no-cache-dir` as I read somewhere else but didn't work at all. I already did `brew install gcc` but it didn't work out. I deleted and reinstalled the command line tools through terminal with `xcode-select --install` but still doesn't work.

I can read in the first lines that it says "Requirement already satisfied" but I checked and imread is definitely not installed.

**Environment**:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.4
- python 3.7.7 (I tried installing it in python 2.7 using just pip but
  still doesn't work).
- pip version = pip 20.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

if anyone can find the solution I would be very grateful! I've been looking for hours for the solution and I can't find it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pkg-config` package. For MacOSX you may find it either in [Brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pkg-config) or in other software collections like [thus sourceforge repository](http://macpkg.sourceforge.net/)

The second (and perhaps the actual) error is the error with gcc. Considering the line

```
 imread/lib/base.h:138:46: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
      void push_back(std::unique_ptr<Image>&& p) { content.push_back(p.release()); }
```

I expect your `gcc` being quite old. What is its actual version? Try to run `gcc -v` to find out.

Update:

As a non-Mac user I would go with `gcc` :-) . To install gcc-9+ from brew, use `brew install gcc` command. Then check that `gcc` and `g++` are actually installed:

```
g++-9 --version
```

I would also check the C++ standard library as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940219/3159253 :

```
`gcc-9 -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

Make sure the paths point to relatively recent version of C++ library, not to 4.2.1 as in your comment.

You should then explicitly use it when running `pip`:

```
CC=gcc-9 pip install imread
```

Comment: I did gcc -v and the output was:
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Ouch. It seems it uses *quite* outdated `libstdc++` headers (`-with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`).

Probably you have no other option than to update the toolchain

Comment: Thank you! The truth is that I am very new to the environment and I don't know much about these tools, you would help me a lot by telling me how to update that!

Comment: I already had gcc installed via brew but I reinstalled it anyways. 'g++-9 --version' returns 'g++-9 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0'. The paths point to relatively recent version of C++ library, not to 4.2.1. 'CC=gcc-9 pip install imread' gives me an error of 'gcc-9: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'
    error: command 'gcc-9' failed with exit status 1'. Cant install it :(

Comment: Looks like `pip` on MacOSX is hardcoded to be clang-only. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654682/unrecognized-command-line-option-stdlib-libc-gcc-homebrew-gcc-5-3-0-5-3-0 . Then it seems that the only only "proper" way is to update clang compiler. Alternatively you could find where the Python PIP machinery forms the command line for a C++ compiler and remove the `-stdlib=...`  part, but I would try to stay with the defaults. You should try to update clang shipped with Xcode tools, or https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/24/installing-llvm-clang-on-osx/

Answer (score 1):

It says quite clearly:

```
sh: pkg-config: command not found
```

So you have to install `pkg-config` and try again.

Comment: I do have pkg-config installes via brew. any idea why it says command not found?