# pip fails to install imread - gcc-9: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'

Tags: python, c++, gcc, pip, imread

So I was trying to install imread with pip3 but I had some old version of gcc(4.2), so I installed it via brew but when I do `CC=gcc-9 pip3 install imread` I get the following error:

```
matinsaurralde@Matiass-MacBook-Pro ~ % CC=gcc-9 pip3 install imread
Collecting imread
  Using cached imread-0.7.4.tar.gz (151 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from imread) (1.17.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: imread
  Building wheel for imread (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-wheel-eg1yplt3
       cwd: /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/
  Complete output (87 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/imread_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/ijrois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/special.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  copying imread/imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_tiff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_rois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_webp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_jpeg.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_imread_from_blob.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_xcf.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_formats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_imsave.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_bad.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  copying imread/tests/test_bmp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/good.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/bit1.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/1_webp_a.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/rois.zip -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/rgba.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/ghsystem_flame.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/star1.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/stack.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/T -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/0186-0099.roi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.unknown -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/good -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/arange512_16bit.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/diag.xcf -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/palette_zero.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/py-installer-indexed.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/mono.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  copying imread/tests/data/error.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF/00r00.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r05.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r04.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r06.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r03.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r02.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r00.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r01.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
  running build_ext
  building 'imread._imread' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib
  gcc-9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/_imread.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/_imread.o -stdlib=libc++
  gcc-9: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'
  error: command 'gcc-9' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imread
  Running setup.py clean for imread
Failed to build imread
Installing collected packages: imread
    Running setup.py install for imread ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-record-9pvbx4kh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/imread
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/
    Complete output (87 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/imread_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/ijrois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/special.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    copying imread/imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_tiff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_rois.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_webp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_jpeg.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_imread_from_blob.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_imread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_xcf.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_formats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_imsave.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_bad.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    copying imread/tests/test_bmp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/good.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/bit1.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/1_webp_a.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/rois.zip -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/rgba.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/ghsystem_flame.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/star1.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/stack.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/T -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/0186-0099.roi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.unknown -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/good -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/arange512_16bit.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/diag.xcf -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/palette_zero.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/py-installer-indexed.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/mono.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.tif -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    copying imread/tests/data/error.webp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF/00r00.tiff -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/TIFF
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r05.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r04.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r06.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r03.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r02.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r00.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r/00r01.bmp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/BMP/00r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r/00r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/00r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r/02r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/02r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r/01r02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/01r
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w03.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w02.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w00.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    copying imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w/03w01.lsm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/tests/data/bad-files/LSM/03w
    running build_ext
    building 'imread._imread' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/lib
    gcc-9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/matinsaurralde/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imread/_imread.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/imread/_imread.o -stdlib=libc++
    gcc-9: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'
    error: command 'gcc-9' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-install-z16h3jop/imread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xt/0v5vcz0s2dg46z8x7j6c4yf80000gn/T/pip-record-9pvbx4kh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/imread Check the logs for full command output.
```

The error is clearly in `gcc-9: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'` but I couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49657549/7976758. Any chance of installing LLVM instead of gcc? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgcc%5D+error%3A+unrecognized+command+line+option+%22stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%22

Comment: well unfortunately there's no configure.py inside imread folder so I couldn't follow those steps.