# Compiler issue when installing ruby with RVM: checking whether the C compiler works... no

Tags: ruby, macos, clang, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby with RVM, like `rvm install 2.4.1`.

I've never had issues with this before moving to Mojave, and am really out of my element here.

But I'm getting an error that appears related to clang.

```
ruby-2.4.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.4.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.4.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
We don't know how to ensure that selected compiler 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' exists.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.4.1 - #downloading ruby-2.4.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.4.1 - #extracting ruby-2.4.1 to /Users/me/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1.....
ruby-2.4.1 - #applying patch /Users/me/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.4.1/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.4.1 - #configuring..
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/me/.rvm/log/1575328022_ruby-2.4.1/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

The logs at `/Users/me/.rvm/log/1575328022_ruby-2.4.1/configure.log` are:

```
[2019-12-02 18:07:54] ./configure
current path: /Users/me/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
command(5): ./configure --prefix=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/me/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I've spent several hours on this without any luck.

Can anyone recommend something to try?

### **UPDATE:**

Although this look similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357804/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables), the solution recommended there is referencing xcode 4.3. I'm now on xcode 11.2, which no longer contains the downloads tab in preferences.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357804/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables

Comment: Not related to Rails or Linux, so not sure why you would tag them.

Comment: Have you tried `xcode-select --install`