# Installation of packages has non-zero exit status in R on MacOS

Tags: r, macos, anaconda, conda, devtools

I have been trying to install devtools package in R on MacOS X. I'm using R on anaconda. I'm getting this error.

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/Users/shashank/Library/R/3.6/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘fs’, ‘gh’, ‘usethis’, ‘git2r’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/fs_1.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 820272 bytes (801 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 801 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gh_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 29043 bytes (28 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 28 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 620225 bytes (605 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 605 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/git2r_0.26.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1214783 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 375464 bytes (366 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 366 KB

* installing *source* package ‘fs’ ...
** package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c error.cc -o error.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c dir.cc -o dir.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c utils.cc -o utils.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c link.cc -o link.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c path.cc -o path.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c file.cc -o file.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fs.cc -o fs.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c id.cc -o id.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c unix/getmode.cc -o unix/getmode.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
(cd libuv \
&& CC="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang" CFLAGS="-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/include -fPIC " AR="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar" RANLIB="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs  -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib -L/Users/shashank/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rstudio/lib" ./configure --quiet)
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/x5/g72x4cmj22j7v7st0mxx3fcm0000gn/T/RtmpBEYd0F/R.INSTALL14f1a525d7a20/fs/src/libuv':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [Makevars:29: libuv/Makefile] Error 77
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fs’
* removing ‘/Users/shashank/Library/R/3.6/library/fs’
* installing *source* package ‘gh’ ...
** package ‘gh’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: object ‘cli_alert_info’ is not exported by 'namespace:cli'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gh’
* removing ‘/Users/shashank/Library/R/3.6/library/gh’
* installing *source* package ‘git2r’ ...
** package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/x5/g72x4cmj22j7v7st0mxx3fcm0000gn/T/Rtmp780q2f/R.INSTALL150401b149ba4/git2r':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
* removing ‘/Users/shashank/Library/R/3.6/library/git2r’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘gh’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘usethis’
* removing ‘/Users/shashank/Library/R/3.6/library/usethis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘usethis’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Users/shashank/Library/R/3.6/library/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/x5/g72x4cmj22j7v7st0mxx3fcm0000gn/T/RtmpysEzOV/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In original(pkgs, lib, repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘fs’ had non-zero exit status
2: In original(pkgs, lib, repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘gh’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10357804 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/216573

Comment: If you installed R through Conda, then don't use `install.packages`. Instead, install all packages through Conda (or Anaconda Navigator).