# C50 package installation error on Mac: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: r, c, macos, anaconda

I am trying to install the package `C50` for R without success.
I use R via Anaconda but the package is not available in the Anaconda environment so I have tried to install it directly from RStudio.

- RStudio version is : Version 1.1.456
- R version is : 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
- Anaconda version is :1.9.7
- MacOS : Catalina 10.15.3

I have both used the standard `install.packages("C50")` as well as the direct installation (using `devtools`) from the GitHub repository.
Searching around it seems that this is an issue related to the SDK headers (? I don't know what that is) and the evolution of the directories in MacOs system over time.

One online search led me here (but again I don't know how to move forward):

https://github.com/conda-forge/compilers-feedstock/issues/11

I reproduce below the message I get when trying to install the package :

```
* installing *source* package ‘Cubist’ ...
** package ‘Cubist’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/sh/hq44lqs10677_vvkvxq01yvh0000gn/T/Rtmpk04dKp/R.INSTALL5020659d63fc/Cubist':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cubist’
* removing ‘/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Cubist’
* restoring previous ‘/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Cubist’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Cubist’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘C50’ ...
** package ‘C50’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/sh/hq44lqs10677_vvkvxq01yvh0000gn/T/Rtmp2NjIsn/R.INSTALL50b47eac3131/C50':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘C50’
* removing ‘/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/C50’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C50’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/sh/hq44lqs10677_vvkvxq01yvh0000gn/T/RtmpdUmDxS/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Another hint is to look in the `config.log` but I don't know how to find it.

I don't know how to interpret this message and any hint would be great.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your `xcode` license expired. Try running:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

in the command line and then agreeing with the license.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am suggesting to try this because it has solved very similar issues for me in the past. Here is the answer I got this from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19993810/1953718

Comment: Thank you @KarolisKoncevičius. When I run that command in the terminal I get : xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Comment: @atalantafugiens Can you try `xcode-select --install` first?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius, yes that is what I did next but got : xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates